# After upgrading to Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow), can't send or receive SMS texts?

Tags: sms, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-6

After upgrading to Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow), I can't send or receive SMS texts.

I'm on a Galaxy S6 on Verizon. I tried rebooting in Safe Mode, disabling Google Hangouts, uninstalling Mighty Text, with no change in status. I used Samsung Messages, Google Messenger, all with no results. I don't have permission to edit my Access Point Names.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by doing this:

Go to Settings -> Privacy and Safety -> App permissions -> SMS

Turn off the Messages app and turn it back on.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to factory reset my phone in the meantime, so have been unable to check if the above worked! Shoot.

Answer (score 1):

Settings>Privacy and Safety> App permissions> SMS> more (top right corner)> Show system> and finally turn on Message service. Helped for me. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I Found the problem on my phone, uninstall all other messaging apps like (whats app,Telegram, imo , Facebook messenger ... ) then your phone starts to work, mine was Telegram app that cause the problem .